# Python: Why is “~” now included in the set of reserved characters in urllib.parse.quote()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urlencode

The most [recent documentation for `urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse) states:

> Changed in version 3.7: Moved from RFC 2396 to RFC 3986 for quoting URL strings. “~” is now included in the set of reserved characters.

Why is this the case? In [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396.html), `~` is not a reserved character:

> ```
>  reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims
>
>  gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
>
>  sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
>              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
> ```

Explicitly in [the next section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396.html#section-2.3) it is included as an unreserved character:

> 2.3.  Unreserved Characters
>
> Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved
> purpose are called unreserved.  These include uppercase and lowercase
> letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.
>
> ```
>  unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
> ```

Furthermore, [later on](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#section-2.4), the RFC states that (emphasis mine):

> For example, the octet corresponding to the tilde ("~") character is often encoded as "%7E" by **older** URI processing implementations;

So it seems like 3.7 is inconsistent: it asserts the support for the newer RFC while simultaneously regressing the processing of `~`. (In fact, in the [older RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396.html#section-2.2), `~` is also not reserved nor '[unwise](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396.html#section-2.4.3)')

Comment: `urllib.parse.quote('~')` does in fact yield `'~'` instead of `%7E`, so it's definitely not reserved. However, `urllib.parse.quote('ñ')` yields `'%C3%B1'`

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/urllib/parse.py#L755-L756 has `reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | "," | "~"`, but there is no detailed explanation.

Comment: It looks like someone misread the but report in [#16285](https://bugs.python.org/issue16285). The author was asking for `~` to be added to an explicit list of safe characters like `-` and `_`, so `quote('/~connolly')` would stop yielding `'/%7econnolly/'`. But it got added to the list of reserved characters instead of to a list of safe characters. (Although the ultimate problem ended up fixed anyway, somehow?)

Answer (score 2):

This bug was tracked and closed in https://bugs.python.org/issue16285

And indeed, the most recent version of the code reflects the changes.

Ref https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/urllib/parse.py

```
_ALWAYS_SAFE = frozenset(b'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
                     b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                     b'0123456789'
                     b'_.-~')
```

Comment: No the documentation representers the intended functionality - which is that `~` should not be encoded. However, the code was incorrect and has now been fixed. So the latest code *does indeed* follow RFC 3986, just as the documentation says it does.

Comment: huh? The documentation says "~" is reserved, when it should not be, as demonstrated by the RFC and the code.